# list items vertical aligment with :after elements

Tags: html, css, html-lists

im trying to realize this design that i made. I created the borders with an :after elements solution, but the problem is that the titles are docking on top of them

The Code

```css
ul {
  width: 150px;
}

li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

li:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 50%; /* or 100px */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

[image: Design]

[image: What it looks like]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the titles are docking on top of them". Is the first screenshot what it's supposed to look like? Then the only difference I see is that the list in the second screenshot isn't centered.

Comment: This question is not very clear - what is the actual problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here using custom changes in css, you can get what you want

```css
ul{
 width: 150px;
    }

    li{
            text-decoration: none;
            list-style-type: none;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            line-height:20px;
            vertical-align:middle;
        }

  li:after{  content : "";
  position: absolute;
  left    : 25%;
  bottom  : -12px;
  height  : 1px;
  width   : 50%;  /* or 100px */
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
       <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
       <li>test</li>
    <li>test testtesttesttesttesttest</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `li` style with this,

```
li {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    /* margin-top: 10px; */
    /* margin-bottom: 10px; */
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Just added the padding instead of margin and line-height only.

Please check the demo https://jsfiddle.net/wfo2dkh1/